# Logs always showing ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG in dev org

Tags: managed-package, debugging, debug

I am developing in a namespaced DE org (not packaged yet) and using standard SFDC_DevConsole debug levels (Apex = Debug, System = Debug, DB = Info) with no trace overrides. But all I see in the logs are my debug statements, queries, profiling info, and rows showing ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG.

This is a relatively newer org (created in late Feb 2016) and I haven't seen this behaviour in other managed DE orgs. So I can't tell where the problem is.

Btw I'm not sure if others have noticed this but the debugger has become somewhat unreliable as of late. For instance overriding debug levels for Apex classes does not always kick into effect. This was experienced recently in a customer org.

Comment: Related: [ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG logging level](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/15058/102)

Comment: There is also the idea: [Debug logging level that will prevent ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG appearing in the log](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kzpbAAA)

Comment: @DanielBallinger Unlike R. Sosemann's case (in the thread you posted) I am getting these lines regardless of whether test cases are running. I am going to chalk it up as a SF release bug for now. As for the idea on the ideaexchange, while I find it useful (voted) I'm not sure if it helps here. These lines are hiding away valuable information, so if they are removed all I achieve is more room in my debug log.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that it *should* be possible to avoid the `ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG` log entries by using an Apex Code logging level above INFO. I.e. WARN or ERROR.

Generally this works. However, there have been cases reported where changing the log level doesn't filter it out as expected. Voting for [Debug logging level that will prevent ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG appearing in the log](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kzpbAAA) may help here.

With regards to the Developer Console not always applying the selected log levels. I found an oddity that was introduced in Winter `16 - [Salesforce Debug logs with the Winter '16 Developer Console](http://www.fishofprey.com/2015/10/salesforce-debug-logs-with-winter-16.html). Basically, by default all users share the same DebugLevel configuration. So if one user makes changes it affects all the users who are using the default configuration.

Comment: It sounds like another case of a resurfacing bug. I have one more reason to build my own debugger now!

Comment: @Mossi I've always found the `ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG` entries a bit odd. I'm yet to see the value in them and they can consume 80%+ of the log file at times. I made my own [log parser](http://www.fuseit.com/explorer) to filter them out.

Comment: Is this suddenly worse in Summer 17?  With my logging set to Apex: ERROR and all other categories set to NONE, I'm hitting the log size limits with only CODE_UNIT_STARTED, CODE_UNIT_FINISHED, and ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG lines.  Trying class-level filters (Set all to NONE) on the triggers invoking the managed code is useless as well.  At this point my log files are unusable.

Comment: Removing logging statements from the non-test-class code seems to have caused the system to start suppressing ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG messages according to my current log level.  I don't have a solid set of repro steps, but I'm able to produce debug output from my test class again.